# Is there a way to search Flickr photos by camera type?

Tags: flickr

Weekly, I tend to browse the [Explore](http://www.flickr.com/explore/) section or sometimes basic searches to see if I can reproduce any shots. To keep things realistic, I do not own a DSLR so a lot of shots are ignored. Is it possible to filter searches so that I can only get a certain camera type.

Where the camera type is displayed in the Additional information section. I know there is the Camera Finder Setup (e.g. photos with [iPhone](http://www.flickr.com/cameras/apple/iphone_3gs/) ) How about the reverse ? Searching photos then applying the filter ?

The reason for this is that say I wanted to check only Creative Commons-licensed content , I would select this in advanced search... but then I lose the camera filter. (maybe I am missing a step)

Comment: Not an answer to your question exactly, but Pbase does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advanced search does seem to lose the camera finder filter. If you copy the URL argument for the camera type;

> &cm=apple%2Fiphone_3gs

and paste it in at the end of your CC licensed software search

> http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=tree&l=cc&ss=0&ct=0&mt=all&w=all&adv=1&cm=apple%2Fiphone_3gs

You can get the results you require. A bit hacky but it does work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do you go to find the list of camera types?  I have a Moto X 2nd Generation, but the camera type strings I am trying, based purely on a guess, does not filter the results. However, the Apple example you provide does, which makes me think after 5 years that this feature is still supported. Thank you.

Comment: Found the list, which allegedly includes all cameras used in the Flickr community; however, the Moto X 2nd Gen, of which I have used as an active member of the Flickr community, is for whatever reason not listed:  https://www.flickr.com/cameras/motorola/.  Hope this helps others.